# How forbid to call member function for temporary object (C++)

Tags: c++, lvalue

I have the template class `data_ptr` which has the member `operator *` for access to the pointer to data:

```
operator T*() { return m_pPtr; }
```

Also inside the constructor of `data_ptr` its pointer is "pinned" in memory and in destructor is "unpinned".

I want to forbid using the `operator*` is this way:

```
data_ptr<T> GetSomeDataPtr { return data_ptr<T>(...); }
T *pRawPointerToData = *GetSomeDataPtr();
```

... because the function `GetSomeDataPtr` returns the temporary object `data_ptr`, and when the destructor gets called its data pointer becomes invalid, so we get a crash when accessing the `pRawPointerToData`.

So, the main idea is to use compiler to find such code. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

Example:

```
template <class T> class data_ptr
{
public:
    data_ptr(T val) : p(new T(val)) {}
    ~data_ptr() {delete p;} 

    operator T*() { return p; } 

private:
    T *p;
};

template <class T>
data_ptr<T> GetSomeDataPtr(T val)
{
    return data_ptr<T>(val);
}

int main() 
{
    int &rawReferenceToData = *GetSomeDataPtr<int>(123);    
    rawReferenceToData = 456;  // << invalid access to already deleted object!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Non `const` member functions can't be called for temporary objects. Give a more concise example of what you have tried, and why it didn't workk please.

Comment: Um... But the code you provided does not call your `operator T*()`. It actually appears to call `operator *()`. And later in the text you also talk about `operator *`. So, what operator is this question supposed to be about: dereference (`operator *()`) or conversion (`operator T*()`)?

Comment: Added full code.

Comment: That's not an `operator*`. That's an implicit conversion operator to `T*`. What actually happens is that your object is implicitly converted to `T*` and then the built-in pointer dereference is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare `operator T*` with an *lvalue ref-qualifier*, i.e.

```
operator T*() & { return p; }
```

so that this conversion can be called only for a lvalue of `data_ptr`, which means a temporary (rvalue) is forbidden to call this conversion.

There are also some defects with your design. Even if an object is not a temporary, it will be destroyed later at some time, and those `T*`s previously exposed do not know the destroy, which has potential danger of invalid access. As a result, it is the caller's responsibility to guarantee no invalid access, so you don't have to limit this call for temporary objects. As an example, `std::string::c_str` can be called on temporaries.