# C++: operator-() how does it act on rvalues?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, rvalue-reference

I have implemented several operators (=, +, +=, etc.) on a custom class (a mathematical vector in this case) for both vector reference inputs, as well as rvalue reference inputs:

Implementing the `operator-()`, used as `Vector a = -b;` I realized, that it also works for rvalues (i.e. `Vector a = -Vector{};`), without me having implemented anything specific for rvalues.

What is happening under the hood? And why is it working for rvalues? It seems like I'm missing something about the way operators are called?

Comment: `Vector{}.foo();` [works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/7GjTx9MYx).

Comment: What makes you think you can't call `Vector{}.foo()`?

Comment: `=`, `+`, `+=`, aren't constructors, btw. As to "how it works" `Vector a = -Vector{}` will create a new `Vector` object (the right hand side) using the no-params constructor. It will then call the unary `-` operator on the newly created object, which you're implemented, then call the copy constructor (or elide here) into the `a` variable.

Comment: Can we get a [mre] of code that does not compile? Include compiler version and flags.

Comment: "Why is my code working?" is a breath of fresh air.  The answer is "Because of the way you wrote it."   We can't go into further details, since we can not see this working code.

Comment: If you *don't* want a method to be callable on an rvalue, you can mark it with an *lvalue ref-qualifier* so it can only be called on an lvalue, eg: `class Vector { public: Vector operator-() &; };` See [How forbid to call member function for temporary object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879222/).

Comment: Hey guys, I corrected my question (it does work for Vector{}.foo()). In any case. I guess that the piece of information I was missing is that any object wether rvalue or lvalue has access to it's public member variables/functions unless its prohibited specifically. Correct? For some reason I had a feeling there had to be an explicit instruction to allow it for rvalues.